# gitlab Failed to connect to dockerdemo-mvc port 3892 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Tags: .net, docker, gitlab-ci

When i run curl command i am getting "Failed to connect to dockerdemo-mvc port 3892 after 0 ms: Connection refused" any thought why it's getting this error? I tried localhost/docker..etc still all are failing

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
    default:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - build
  - acceptance

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  IMAGE_NAME: docker.dotnetcoredemo

curl api testing:
  stage: acceptance
  image: curlimages/curl
  services:
  - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:api
    alias: dockerdemo-mvc
  script:
    - sleep 15
    - curl http://dockerdemo-mvc:3892/api/customers
```

pipeline:
[pipeline][1]

public test repo in gitlab.
https://gitlab.com/venkat-test-group/Docker.DotNetCoreDemo
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqLra.png

Edited and tested based on suggestion (but still not working)

```
docker-pull:
  stage: pull
  image: docker:latest
  before_script:
    - docker --version
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:api

curl api testing:
  stage: acceptance
  image: curlimages/curl
  services:
    - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:api
      alias: dockerdemo-api
  script:
    - sleep 15
    - curl http://dockerdemo-api:3892/api/customers
  environment:
     name: staging
  dependencies:
    - docker-pull
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output from `curl`, the dockerdemo-mvc service isn't running.

I would pull the `$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:api` and run it locally. Follow the logs, then hit the API with `curl`.

Comment: Edited original post but still getting same error.